# Sitecore 8, .NET 4.6, Bundles Returning 404

Tags: sitecore, asp.net-optimization, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I am running Sitecore 8 (Update 5) on .NET 4.6 and am running into an issue with Bundles returning a 404 error.

My layout view:

```html
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@using Sitecore.Mvc

@model RenderingModel

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>@Model.Item.Fields["Title"]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title")</h1>
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content")

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" defer=\"defer\"></script>", "~/bundles/scripts/footer")
    </body>
    </html>
```

My ***/Global.asax.cs*** file:

```c#
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;

namespace Sitecore.Web
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Items["Disable"] = new VersionCountDisabler();
        }
    }
}
```

My ***/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs*** file:

```c#
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/footer").Include(
            "~/Assets/js/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Assets/js/additional-methods.js",
            "~/Assets/js/form.js",
            "~/Assets/js/marketo.js"
        ));


        #if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        #else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        #endif
    }
}
```

The `<system.webServer>/modules` section of my ***/Web.config***:

```xml
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Web.RewriteModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreRewriteModule" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Nexus" name="SitecoreHttpModule" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreUploadWatcher" />
  <add type="Sitecore.IO.XslWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXslWatcher" />
  <add type="Sitecore.IO.LayoutWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreLayoutWatcher" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreConfigWatcher" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" />
  <add type="Sitecore.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreHttpModuleExtensions" />
  <add name="SitecoreAntiCSRF" type="Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.SitecoreAntiCsrfModule, Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf" />
  <remove name="BundleModule"/>
  <add type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" name="BundleModule"/>
</modules>
```

And lastly, the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting as displayed by ***/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx*** that shows /bundles is included in the list:

```xml
<!--
  IGNORE URLS
            Set IgnoreUrlPrefixes to a '|' separated list of url prefixes that should not be
            regarded and processed as friendly urls (ie. forms etc.)

-->
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|/bundles|/Assets"/>
```

**UPDATE:** See accepted answer below.

Comment: Don't think sitecore is ready for 4.6 yet. Still haven't done regression tests. 8.0 just released with 4.5 and mvc 5.2. Probably going to be a bit before 4.6 gets pushed (or at least until it's supported).

Comment: I changed the build target to 4.5 and the same behavior occurs.   The 404 error page indicates that the Handler is StaticFile, which to me would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was.   The "inherits" attribute of the markup of my Global.asax did not match the class name in the Global.asax.cs.

Comment: Tricky. I like to use WebActivatorEx as an alternative to modifying the Global.asax.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904486/how-can-i-add-defer-attribute-in-the-sitecore-foundation-frameworks-min-js

Answer (score 0):

Time to experiment:

1. Remove your compiler directives. `<compilation debug="true|false">` should control that at runtime.
2. Remove your web.config `<module>` entries. I've found this hasn't been necessary for even Sitecore 7.2 projects.

Comment: Tried these.   No change in behavior.

Comment: No physical folder named /bundles on disk?

Comment: No physical folder named /bundles on disk.

Comment: Use a virtual path other than /bundles?